# Why is STDIN open by default for programs running in SystemD?

Tags: c, io, stdin, systemd

I have an if-statement at the top of a C main method, which checks if STDIN is open.  If it is open, the program prints an error and exits.  This is mainly for documentation reasons.  I don't want users of the program to assume passing things to STDIN is supported.

A problem arose when I tried to execute this program as a SystemD daemon, however.

It seems like SystemD programs always have an open STDIN pipe.

Why is this?  Can it be avoided?

Comment: Why are you checking for this? Why not just close stdin yourself, and if they try to actually write anything to it they'll get an error? It's very weird to insist it be closed *by them*. Tons of programs don't take input from stdin (e.g. `ls`) but they just ignore it, they're not validating that it's closed.

Comment: C programs in a hosted environment (such as normal Linux systems) are entitled to assume standard input, standard output and standard error will be open for them to use.  They might be connected to something like `/dev/null`, in which case, any read operations will report EOF and write operations will succeed but the output will be lost.  If you don't want that, you'll have to take steps to close standard input (and, presumably, standard output and standard error).  But the programs may fail unexpectedly if you close those file streams, as opposed to redirecting them harmlessly.

Comment: See C11 [§7.21.3 Files ¶7](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.3p7): _At program startup, three text streams are predefined and need not be opened explicitly -- standard input (for reading conventional input), standard output (for writing conventional output), and standard error (for writing diagnostic output). As initially opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered; the standard input and standard output streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an interactive device._

Comment: @ShadowRanger mainly for documentation… don't want users assuming STDIN carries any functionality.  Would prefer to just shut it down straight away.  I'm doing the same for extraneous command line arguments -- immediate error message and exit.

Comment: @SeánHealy: Error messages for extraneous command line arguments are normal. *Nobody* requires stdin be closed.

Comment: Unless you go to heroic methods (manually closing fd 0 and then manually calling `exec`), STDIN should ALWAYS be open on something in the top of main.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I hadn't realised that initially, because when the program is run by the user in a terminal without any other elements at play, STDIN is then closed.

Comment: When a program is run by a user in a terminal without any other elements at play, STDIN will be connected to the terminal, not closed.  If the terminal is a pseudo-terminal that is later destroyed, reading from stdin will return EOF, but it will still be open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's kinda bad if fd 0 isn't opened because the next open would result in fd 0 being used. It's therefore common to have it open, but reading from `/dev/null`.

Comment: While I can't find anything in the standard, all POSIX systems will ensure that fds 0, 1, and 2 are open for any program that is started in any "normal" way, since failing to do so would likely lead to problems in any program that tried to open anything and unexpected got fd 0, 1, or 2.

Comment: @Chris Dodd Maybe. But there are plenty of wonky stuff that can happen before you launch a child a program (if you do at all). In fact, if you were to launch a program using `system` , the pipe to communicate errors back to the parent that would normally be on fd 3 or higher will ends up on fd 0.

Comment: My point exactly -- if any of 0, 1, or 2 are close prior to starting a program, all kinds of things are liable to misbehave.

Comment: Detail: `system()` doesn't use a pipe to communicate errors back to the parent.  In fact, neither does `popen()`.  Both leave errors from the child going to `stderr` unless you do something to send them elsewhere.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, I'm not talking about stderr, but `exec` errors. The system I'm using uses `clone` rather than `fork`+`exec`, but a system that uses `fork`+`exec` can use a close-on-exec pipe to communicate `exec` failures to the parent so they appear as `system` failures (and set `errno`) rather than status errors obtained using `wait`.

Comment: @Chris Dodd, But you suggested that POSIX would make sure fd 0 is an open handle. My comment pointed out that would happen too late. Plenty can go wrong before that will happen in the process that closed stdin. The process might not even launch a child for which POSIX would make sure fd 0 is open.

Comment: My belief is that POSIX effectively requires all conforming shells and program launchers (such as systemd) start applications with fds 0, 1, and 2 open, but I can't find a specific statement to that effect in the standard, so perhaps not.

Comment: @Chris Dodd What makes you thinkthe OP's program is a "conforming shell or program launcher"?

Comment: @ikegami: He's asking about systemd specifically, which is a pretty standard part of Linux systems.

Comment: @Chris Dodd, They mentioned SystemD, but the question is *why*, and the answer is *cause it could easily cause problems for a program if it doesn't have an open fd 0/1/2*. Whether the program is a "conforming shell or program launcher" or not is irrelevant to this answer. /// If you're trying to say that SystemD has specific obligations in this regard, that has nothing to do with my answer, and you should post that as an answer as that would also answer *why* more specifically. I don't even know what SystemD is.

Answer (score 1):

When a daemon is started on pretty much any POSIX-style system, it will have fds 0 (stdin) and 1 (stdout) connected to /dev/null (fd 2 (stderr) may be connected to /dev/null or maybe to some logging service)

It's pretty much required to have them open, since leaving them closed would result in the next call that returned a new descriptor returning one of these -- POSIX requires that any new file descriptor always be allocated to the lowest index that is not currently open: [POSIX File Descriptor Allocation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_14).

---

If you expect some program to always be started as a daemon, it may make sense to ensure that stdin and stdout are not connected to any tty device (use isatty(3) for this).